# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A.json'

Tags: python, json, networkx, mininet

could you please let me know how to fix this error, I'm try to run a python code, but when I run the code it gave the about error. I don't have a lot coding experiences and I really need to fix this.
please help and advise me on how to fix it.

```
import networkx as nx

def path_valid(g, p):
""" Checks whether the list nodes p is a valid path in g."""
plen = len(p)
for i in range(plen-1):
 if not g.has_edge(p[i],p[i+1]):
     return False
return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
g = nx.Graph()  # Create an empty undirected graph
g.add_node(1); g.add_node(2); g.add_node(3)
g.add_edge(1,2); g.add_edge(1,3); g.add_edge(2,3)
print "Graph nodes are: {}".format(g.nodes())
print "Graph edges are: {}".format(g.edges())
print "Is edge (2,1) in the graph? {}".format(g.has_edge(2,1))
print "Is edge (3,2) in the graph? {}".format(g.has_edge(3,2))
print "Is path [1,3,2] valid? {}".format(path_valid(g, [1,3,2]))
print "Is path [1,4,2] valid? {}".format(path_valid(g, [1,4,2]))

from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import json
g = nx.Graph()
# Don't need to add nodes separately.
g.add_edge(1,2, capacity=10)  # add a "capacity" parameter
g.add_edge(1,3, capacity=10)  # can have any name you like
g.add_edge(2,3, capacity=15)
print "Graph nodes are: {}".format(g.nodes())
print "Graph edges are: {}".format(g.edges(data=True))
print "Is edge (2,1) in the graph? {}".format(g.has_edge(2,1))
print "Is edge (3,2) in the graph? {}".format(g.has_edge(3,2))
print "The capacity of edge (2,3) is {}".format(g[2][3]["capacity"])
# print graph as a JSON string
# print graph as a JSON string
print json.dumps(json_graph.node_link_data(g),indent=4)
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import networkx as nx
import json
# Read in a JSON formatted graph file
g = json_graph.node_link_graph(json.load(open("A.json")))
print "graph nodes: {}".format(g.nodes())  # Lists nodes
print "graph links: {}".format(g.edges(data=True))  #  Shows link info
for n in g.nodes():  # See that hosts are assigned addresses
if g.node[n]["type"] == 'host':
    print "Host {}, IP = {}, MAC = {}".format(n, g.node[n]['ip'], g.node[n]['mac'])
```

I got this error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/my_python.py", line 42, in <module>
g = json_graph.node_link_graph(json.load(open("A.json")))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A.json'
```

please if you need the whole code let me know so I can send it to you.
Thank you for your help and supports.

Comment: First, do you actually have a file named `A.json`? (Remember that filenames are case-sensitive on Linux.) If so, is it in the same directory as your current working directory when you run your Python script?

Comment: It's just missing the file "A.json" -- do you have that file?  It's trying to open and load it on line 42, but is failing because it can't find it.

Comment: I don't have ut, could you please check the code now, I just add the whole code.
Thank you.